# Limiting the monitor to a region in Linux

Tags: c++, linux, graphics, monitor, x11

I have a laptop with a broken 13 inch display. The left half of the display is completely black and I cant's fix it for now. I was wondering if it's possible to write a program in any language to limit the display to the right, that means either:

1. Changing the resolution to have half of the width it currently has **or**
2. Keep the aspect ratio but zoom out the display and send it to the right.

I am preferably looking for a method that can be used in Linux (Windows will be in second priority)

The language is not an issue (though I am assuming C++ would be the way to go) and I'm looking for some hints.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you joking? buy a new monitor or get a used one from a colleague, thats cheaper even for chinese development salary.

Comment: @AlexWien It's not an issue of money. I live in an embargoed country so It's not easy to find such things :( On the other hand, I am a programmer, it's an urge of wanting to experiment weird things!

Comment: I think it is possible in Xorg ..  Take a look at the xrand option mentioed here: http://superuser.com/questions/248840/limit-video-output-to-a-section-of-a-display-and-leave-the-rest-blank

Comment: +1 but it has nothing much to do with any language. it has to do with platform specific display drivers. However you may do it programatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change resolution using [xrandr](http://www.perpetualpc.net/srtd_resolution.html) Linux command.

Answer (score 3):

maybe (if `xrandr` don't make you happy) you could use [Xnest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xnest), position the Xnest root window appropriately, and run all other X11 applications inside that `Xnest`.